# UIautomator - Android Studio - How to generate an APK or JAR file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-uiautomator

I have a project in Android Studio, using UIAutomator, but I don't want to open Android studio everytime I need to run it.

How can I generate a APK, Jar file or anything that can be launched? I don't want smart or safe methods, but the simple the better. It has to be using Android Studio, not eclise or any other IDE.

It generates APK, but it doesn't open properly, I don't have any GUI coded, just test classes.

Thanks,

Answer (score -2):

Only way you can achieve this by storing APK on your android mobile, here is simplest way to do so

Connect your android mobile and choose the device as emulator while running the project,by doing this you will find APK installed on your mobile device that you can run anytime you want.

here are steps to follow :-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb2olFyoMV4

Comment: I could get the apk but the problem is it doesn't work (force closes). I didn't do any android interface, only java classes with uiautomator to perform actions on my device.